# URL optimization with php

Tags: url-rewriting

i've been trying several ways to optimize the url that result when the DB of my [site](http://www.ferreteriaprogresemos.com) is consulted, changing .htaccess adding some php at the top, and some other ways that include both, but nothing happens, there are many ways all around the web but i'm feeling unlucky and kind of powerless trying to implement any of those ways, i just can't make it work.

The products catalog is organized in a very popular way in a MySql DB, nothing revolutionary or unique, $_GET method and that's all, you got the department, category or product that the user clicks. Can you give me some help with this? it is kind of basic for advanced developers but clearly i am not one. thanks in advance for your time!

the .htaccess code here:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule testpage\.html http://www.google.com [R]
RewriteRule ^catalog/(\d+) catalogo.php?cat=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^department/(\d+) catalogo.php?dpto=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^producto/(\d+) producto.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't know if there is a simple way to explain htaccess, but that is likely the most painless way to change a url from yoursite.com?category=1 to something like yoursite.com/category/1 - there are a lot of tutorials out there. You just have to be patient and follow instructions

Comment: do you have some instructions link to visit and follow? i've been as patient as i could but theres too much info and i'm going crazy, each tutorial says something different and it appears to work in some cases for everybody but me... thanks for your answer and your time reading my question.

Comment: Tell you what - you give an example of a url and we might be able to show you a basic htaccess rule to apply to it.

Comment: when i click some department it is 
www.mysite.com/catalog.php?dpt=2 (id of the department) when i click some category inside the department it shows www.mysite.com/catalog.php?cat=6 (id of the category), if i click some product in the category it is www.mysite.com/product.php?id=1845 (id of the product), that's what it shows. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, now what do you want it to be? www.mysite.com/catalog/6 for example? I'll type out a basic htaccess rule. htaccess is enabled, correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^catalog/(\d+) catalog.php?cat=$1 [L,NC]
```

That is a basic regex to match category (\d+) - any digit - and map it to category.php?cat= then $1 means to plug in the number found in the first parenthesis (6) for example.

```
RewriteRule ^department/(\d+) catalog.php?dpt=$1 [L,NC]
```

That would work for department.

You can place whatever you like in the url, should you decide to get more specific -

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/department/(\d+) catalog.php?dpt=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^catalog/category/(\d+) catalog.php?cat=$1 [L,NC]
```

Remember, `RewriteEngine On` must be in .htaccess before any rules are set.

Typically, the whole thing is wrapped in a conditional, like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^catalog/department/(\d+) catalog.php?dpt=$1 [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^catalog/category/(\d+) catalog.php?cat=$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: first i want to thank you for your answer, i'm trying but i can't make it work, i just don't know what i'm doing wrong, or what i'm missing... i wish that i could get something like www.mysite.com/catalog/hammers/, but no matter what it is still getting the same complicated url.

Comment: ¿Can be possible that my site isn't suitable for doing this url optimization?

Comment: it's possible mod_rewrite is not enabled. Also, catalog/hammers/ would not match the rule outlined in this answer. it is expecting a number. You would have to make you php code pull from the database by name for your hammer url to work. and then you would replace \d+ with \w+

Comment: it is enabled, i put RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule testpage\.html http://www.google.com [R] then i tested it and it redirect me to google, i don't have problem if it makes the url with the id, but what can be happening with this matter? i still can't understand why it is not working...

Comment: I just ran a test on my server and it works as expected. Can you update your question with the entire contents of your htaccess file? I assume it's empty, but you never know. There may be a conflicting line somewhere.

Comment: updated! that's all the content of the .htaccess file. it includes the test that redirects to google and it works, i assume that it can be what you say some conflicting line that i can't see. thanks for helping me.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters but you might need to either remove that test redirect or make it [L,R] and not just [R]. Aside that minute possibility, I don't see any errors there. if the redirect is working, you shouldn't need to restart apache or anything like that. I might just in case but that's not a totally logical move. Just a routine when debugging.

Comment: i'll try the reset, and as you said i will test this in another server and see what happens, thanks!